# Arabic is displayed as ????? in velocity template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, velocity

Greetings all
i am using velocity templates in sending emails
and in the template i have some arabic texts

and when sending the email, the text appears like ??????????
i don't know why:

encoding is set to utf-8 before sending the email here:

```
VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,templateName, "UTF-8",newModel);
```

i tried to add the charset in the vm, but with no luck:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

any ideas why such problem occurs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to produce Arabic text (تجاوز سعة مكدس) on a plain-text email sent from a Spring app. The text displayed properly on GMail as well as Thunderbird. Here's my mail sending logic:

```
public void send(String fromAddress, String fromName,
    String toAddress, String subject,
    String template, Map<String, Object> model) {
  MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
    public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
      MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(
          mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
      message.setTo(toAddress);
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress, fromName));
      message.setSubject(subject);
      message.setText(VelocityEngineUtils
          .mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, template, "UTF-8", 
              model));
    }
  };
  mailSender.send(preparator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any velocity.properties set? (particularly input.encoding or output.encoding)  If not, try setting those both to UTF-8 also.